# Transaction in TypeORM

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

i'm with a trouble in my API since last week: I need to make crypto transactions between users, but its not working

transactionService:

```
import { TransactionDto } from './dto.transactions/transaction.dto';
import { UserService } from 'src/user/user.service';
import {DataSource, Repository} from 'typeorm';
import {Body, Injectable, Request, Response} from '@nestjs/common';
import { InjectRepository } from '@nestjs/typeorm';
import { UserEntity } from 'src/user/entities/user.entity';

@Injectable()
export class TransactionsService {
  constructor(@InjectRepository(UserEntity) private readonly repository: Repository<UserEntity>,
  private readonly UserService: UserService,
  private DataSource: DataSource, ) {}


  async cryptoTransactions(@Body() TransactionDto: TransactionDto, @Request() req, @Response() res): Promise<any> {
    const queryRunner = this.DataSource.createQueryRunner();

    await queryRunner.startTransaction();

    const fromUser = req.body.fromId;
    const toUser = req.body.toId;
    const quantityTransfered = req.body.quantityTransfered;

    try {
      (await fromUser).CryptoWallet -= quantityTransfered;
      (await toUser).CryptoWallet += quantityTransfered;

      await queryRunner.manager.save(fromUser)
      await queryRunner.manager.save(toUser)

      await queryRunner.commitTransaction()
      
      return fromUser
     
    } catch (err) {
      await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
    } finally {
      await queryRunner.release();
    }
  }
}
```

transactionsController:

```
import { TransactionsService } from './transactions.service';
import { Body, Controller, Post, Request, Response } from '@nestjs/common';
import { TransactionDto } from './dto.transactions/transaction.dto';

@Controller('transactions')
export class TransactionsController {
constructor(private TransactionsService: TransactionsService) {}

@Post()
async cryptoTransactions(@Body() TransactionDto: TransactionDto, @Request() req, @Response() res) {
    return this.TransactionsService.cryptoTransactions(TransactionDto, req, res)
}
}
```

transactionDto:

```
import { ApiProperty } from "@nestjs/swagger";
import { IsNotEmpty } from "class-validator";

export class TransactionDto {
    @ApiProperty()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    fromId: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    toId: string;

    @ApiProperty()
    @IsNotEmpty()
    quantityTransfered: number
}
```

the "cryptowallet" from each user is not being modified like the "quantityTransfered".

Someone who can helps me?

Answer (score 1):

i solved my problem using "datasource"

```
async cryptoTransactions(@Body() TransactionDto: TransactionDto, @Request() req) {
    const queryRunner = this.DataSource.createQueryRunner();
    await queryRunner.startTransaction();

    try {
      const fromUser = await this.DataSource.getRepository(UserEntity).findOneBy({
        Id: req.body.fromId,
      });
      const toUser = await this.DataSource.getRepository(UserEntity).findOneBy({
        Id: req.body.toId,
      });
      const quantityTransfered = req.body.quantityTransfered;

      if (fromUser) {
        if (toUser) {
          fromUser.CryptoWallet -= quantityTransfered;
          toUser.CryptoWallet += quantityTransfered;

          await this.DataSource.manager.save(fromUser);
          await this.DataSource.manager.save(toUser);

          const transactionSuccesfully = [fromUser, toUser];

          await queryRunner.commitTransaction();

          return transactionSuccesfully;
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      await queryRunner.rollbackTransaction();
    } finally {
      await queryRunner.release();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

use transaction in this way. i solved my problem this way-

```
  await this.repository.manager.transaction(async manager => {
    // do what you want
    await manager.save(fromUser);
  })
```

Comment: thanks by answer. But I solved in another way. I prefered to follow using queryrunner. I'll share that like a answer to the question...